# Support newer .NET framework features in library used in older framework version

Tags: .net, types, .net-3.5, cancellation

I have an asynchronous library which is compiled under .NET 3.5, since it's used by .NET 3.5 applications, but I want to be able to deal with .NET 4.0 CancellationTokens if someone wants to pass one in.  In order to include .NET 4.0 stuff, I have to break compatibility with .NET 3.5.  The only option I've come up with so far would be to just allow passing in "object" and then use reflection, but that makes for an ugly public interface... I want to make sure the client code is passing in the correct object type at compile time, not runtime.

Is there any way to bind against .NET 4.0 objects at compile time, without introducing an unnecessary dependency to consumer applications?  To say "use this feature if it's there, and skip it if it's not"?

Comment: No. since you want the types to be part of your public interface you must compile two different versions.

Comment: Can I suggest a 4.0 version and a 3.5 version of your library may be more pragmatic.

Comment: You could use the directives like this #if !NET_3_5 using statement #endif to help reduce amount of code. Not sure if this is a good practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have the public interfaces that require .NET 4.0 types in a separate assembly, possibly as Extension methods - and if you need to (e.g. interact between the .NET 4 types and the internals of your types in the main assembly) you could define an interface in your main (.NET 3.5) assembly and implement it in the .NET 4 assembly with a wrapper around a .NET 4 type in order to avoid reflection entirely.

Comment: I like this because it deals with the transitive problem:  If assembly X requires assembly Y requires assembly Z, and Z requires 4.0, then that means that X and Y require 4.0.  But with extension methods, Z' can contain 4.0 stuff, and Y can remain 3.5, and X can still use the 4.0 stuff by including Z'.  The main downside is that you're limited to functionality that can be implemented with extension methods.  It would make disposing the CancellationTokenRegistration a bit messier, but not impossible.

Comment: So you wrap the CancellationTokenRegistration in a class (in Z) that implements an interface (defined in Y).